# Not praying Jumma Prayers since April 2020

Tags: salat, jumuah

In Corona Pandemic, I've not prayed any Jumma Prayer since April. Not even in Home as Juhr. As we know about missing 3 jumma sequentially, is it applicable in this corona situation? My nearest mosque was opened.

Comment: You have not been praying Zuhr on Friday since April?

Comment: No, i was not regular to daily prayer, used to offer Jumuah(Jumma) only. In corona, I'm not regularly praying all of the prayer. Attended Eid's Salah, maybe some Waqt in Ramadan.

Comment: You should worry more about your daily prayers than for jumuah at this point.

Comment: You can pray at home due to the Coronavirus (Covid-19) outbreak that is spreading around the world as the Prophet (saw) permitted those who are sick or ill to pray at home, rather than in congregations at the mosque. Even cancelling of the jummua prayers are permitted with worshippers praying zuhr at home in its place. https://rb.gy/mrmhj6